Как записать данные из рекурсии в файл c#?
Есть рекурсия, при выполнении определенных условий данный должны записываться в файл и вот тут возникает проблема, каждый раз в файле остаётся только последнее верное значение, как записывать верные данные без создания каких-то глобальных переменных? Я просто не особо разбираюсь в работе с файлами

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! чем плохи скриншоты (картинки). => https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/264178


называйте переменные с маленькой буквы 2) давайте переменным осмысленные имена


Вам нужно не пересоздавать файл, а добавлять к нему:
new StreamWriter("c:\\file.txt", true);
или
new StreamWriter("c:\\file.txt", append: true);


Да и вообще using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))

@CrazyElf Да и вообще File.AppendAllLines
